# Python 3.4.4 formatting issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, ascii

I am wondering if there is a way to add a string to the end of a input line.

```
print('┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐')
ItemCost = float(input('│Enter item cost: '))
```

This outputs

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Enter item cost: xxxx
```

I would like it to output

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Enter item cost: xxxx                                    │
```

(Excluding the part in the "")

Any help would be appriciated thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight:  I think the question is good enough.  The OP does show some code.  Apart from knowing the answer I don't know what an unsuccessful attempt would look like.  The real problem the OP was dealing with is he was considering it a problem of how to add a string to the end of the input prompt rather than a question of how to reposition the cursor.  Once reframed, I'll bet he could have googled the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ANSI escape codes to reposition the cursor after writing the full line. Note, though, that since `input` writes the prompt to standard error, you'll probably want to include both lines in the call to `input`.

```
prompt = ('┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐\n'
          '│Enter item cost: \033[s                                   |\033[u'))

ItemCost = float(input(prompt))
```

`\033[s` tells the terminal to remember the current position of the cursor; `\033[u` tells the terminal to move the cursor to the currently remembered position.

This requires your terminal to understand ANSI escape codes; a more portable solution would be to use the `curses` library.

Comment: Nice.  ANSI escape codes were a new concept for me.  Here's a [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) if anyone wants to read more.

Comment: Thanks for this link @StevenRumbalski, it'll be useful and fun to discover !

Comment: Where was it stated that output was to an ANSI-conformant terminal?  I don't see that anywhere in the question.  Even if it is writing to a terminal, you should use the standard portable means of obtaining its control sequences.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner's answer is excellent if your terminal understands ANSI escape codes.

The following works on terminals that don't (such as Windows PowerShell):

```
>>> prompt = '''\
... ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
... │Enter item cost:                                          │''' + 42 * '\b'
>>> item_cost = float(input(prompt))
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Enter item cost: 12.5                                     │
>>> item_cost
12.5
```

Unfortunately, backspace (`'\b'`) can only move the cursor on a single line, so you cannot put a bottom on you input box and backspace up to the previous line.  For that you would have to use a `curses` based approach.